# Context cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, android

I am using following code to write a PDF from View using [Android  PrintedPdfDocument API](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/print/pdf/PrintedPdfDocument.html)

```
 PrintedPdfDocument document = new PrintedPdfDocument(context,         
 PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4);
```

But I get following message:

> context cannot be resolved to a variable

What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Where is context being declared and initialized?

Comment: I have only MainActivity with my Webview

Comment: and I've created a new class:    Application {

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        AppContext.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return AppContext.context;
    }
}

Comment: Is `context` declared in the same class as that line above?

Comment: You are setting the context in some kind of cyclic loop it seems. AppContext.context = getApplicationContext(), but getApplicationContext just returns AppContext.context, which will be null.

Comment: No, I  have created another new class: class AppContext extends Application and call it in mainctivity with AppContext.getAppContext()

Comment: Did you try: PrintedPdfDocument document = new PrintedPdfDocument(AppContext.getAppContext(),         
 PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4);

Comment: Yes, I did. In my Manifest I wrote  android:name="AppContext"  too.

Answer (score 1):

The example you are trying to follow assumes that you have a context. So, in your Activity, replace these lines:

```
PrintedPdfDocument document = new PrintedPdfDocument(context,         
 PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4);
```

with:

If your activity extends ContextWrapper, then:

```
PrintedPdfDocument document = new PrintedPdfDocument(this,         
 PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4);
```

otherwise:

```
PrintedPdfDocument document = new PrintedPdfDocument(getContext(),         
     PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4);
```

Comment: I did it but I got the message: "The constructor PrintedPdfDocument(Class<MainActivity>, PrintAttributes.MediaSize) is undefined"